# When using page-break-after, it sometimes doesn't go all the way to the next page

Tags: html

So, the pagebreak works. I've used it on div and hr. When printing on Chrome, by the third page I sometimes get the first line appearing at the end of the previous page. It's not completely breaking to the next page.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">.sf{font-size:10px}table{border-collapse: collapse;margin: 20px;}th{color:white; background-color:DarkSlateGray; font-size:120%;} tr:nth-child(odd){    background-color:lightgray;}@media print {.pagebreak {page-break-after: always;}}</style>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <table width=100%>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>R 1 - T 1</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>az</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>hn</h4>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <table width=100%>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>R 1 - T 6</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>dc</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>u</h4>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <table width=100%>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>R 1 - T 11</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>de</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>t</h4>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <table width=100%>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>R 1 - T 16</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>s2</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>a</h4>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <table width=100%>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>R 1 - T 21</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>f</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>s1</h4>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <table width=100%>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>R 1 - T 26</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>i3</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>gt</h4>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="pagebreak">&nbsp;</div>
    <table width=100%>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>R 1 - T 2</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>lo</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>b</h4>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <table width=100%>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>R 1 - T 7</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>x</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>ui</h4>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <table width=100%>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>R 1 - T 12</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>o</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>q</h4>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <table width=100%>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>R 1 - T 17</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>d</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>n</h4>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <table width=100%>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>R 1 - T 22</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>sx</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>fv</h4>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <table width=100%>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>R 1 - T 3</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>s</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>r</h4>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="pagebreak">&nbsp;</div>
    <table width=100%>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>R 1 - T 8</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>i1</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>aq</h4>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <table width=100%>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>R 1 - T 13</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>ki</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>g</h4>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <table width=100%>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>R 1 - T 18</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>h</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>jm</h4>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <table width=100%>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>R 1 - T 23</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>r1</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>re</h4>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <table width=100%>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>R 1 - T 4</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>fr</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>r2</h4>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <table width=100%>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>R 1 - T 9</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>z</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>s3</h4>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="pagebreak">&nbsp;</div>
    <table width=100%>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>R 1 - T 14</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>c</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>yt</h4>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <table width=100%>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>R 1 - T 19</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>v</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>gb</h4>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <table width=100%>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>R 1 - T 24</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>4</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>e</h4>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <table width=100%>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>R 1 - T 5</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>m</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>r3</h4>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <table width=100%>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>R 1 - T 10</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>k</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>p</h4>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <table width=100%>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>R 1 - T 15</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>sw</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>w</h4>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="pagebreak">&nbsp;</div>
    <table width=100%>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>R 1 - T 20</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>i</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>y</h4>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <table width=100%>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>R 1 - T 25</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>i2</h4>
        </td>
        <td vAlign=bottom align=left>
          <h4>j</h4>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
        <td class="sf">
          <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%;">pk_</div>
          </br>
          <div style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%;"><input type="checkbox">wd</input></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: One thing i have noticed. There are so many divs in your code which are not closed.

Comment: Abbas, you're correct, but I do not think that is relevant. This set of HTML was after a couple different attempts. All of them had the same problem and others did not use divs.

Comment: Updated with closed DIVs and added the @media suggestion from Yaser. No change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use your css inside a media query if you want something to be applied when printing:

```
@media print {
    .pagebreak {page-break-after: always;}
}
```

**Update**:
Since you are using a table this can help you at all times:

```
<table class="print-friendly">
  <!-- The rest of your table here -->
</table>

<style>
    table.print-friendly tr td, table.print-friendly tr th {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance, but where do I add that?

Comment: same place you already have your css, inside `<style></style>` @Chris.Brown.SPE

Comment: Added your suggestion, no change. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: you can check the update, this will definitely help you @Chris.Brown.SPE

Comment: The update helped! Found my major problem though. The CSS that modifies the table border was causing the problem. When I removed it, everything else acted as expected. Thanks!